# How to say "Go ahead, I will follow you later" in other ways?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, conversation

My friends are going out for lunch and ask me to go with them.

I haven't finished my work. I will follow them 10 minutes later.

Normally, what will you say? beside "I will follow you later."

Comment: "I'll join you later", or "I'll meet you there".

Comment: "I'll come along when I'm good and ready" and "I'll get there in my own sweet time."

Answer (score 3):

"You move on, I'll catch up in 10 minutes."

Comment: Can I say "I will catch you up" or "I will catch up with you"?

Comment: "I'll catch up with you" is fine, "I'll catch you up" doesn't sound right.

Comment: "I'll catch you up" *does* sound correct to my British ear, we say it in normal conversation. This is partly because "I'll catch up with you" has the alternate meaning of "I will get together with you later to go over the things I have missed".

Comment: "I'll catch you up" sounds wrong to my American ear. I think most of us in the U.S. would say, "You go ahead. I'll catch up with you."

Comment: @MattЭллен Fascinating difference, as here in the US "I'll catch you up" generally has the "I will later give you the information you missed", while "I'll catch up with you" means "you go ahead and I'll soon join you".

Answer (score 0):

[I'll be] right behind you...

-Personal experience :)